# Recommendation for disk size for GitLab, PostgreSQL and Redis containers

Tags: docker, postgresql, redis, gitlab

At present, GitLab is running as an omnibus docker (includes both postgres and redis as part of single container) and the size of data directory is 500 MB after 2 months of usage. We have around 70 developers. I have to move from the current setup and split GitLab into separate docker images (GitLab, PostegreSQL and Redis).  What should be the recommended size for each container if i have to persist their corresponding data on disk?

I think GitLab will be the one having the maximum space as it will house the code as well. After that PostgreSQL might be the one with lesser space and then Redis with the least. Just guessing. Looking for some figures (GB)

Comment: @Sven: This is not an exact duplicate of the post that you have referred to. That post is quite vague in its requirement. This isn't. I have provided the number of users who will be checking-in stuff into GitLab. I have also provided space utilization based on two month's data. I don't think this is vague.

Comment: The duplicate is meant as a catchall to explain why we will not help you with your capacity planning in principal.

Comment: Ok. Is there any other relevant place (except GitLab IRC, which i have already checked) where i can get some help? SO? I first thought of posting on SO but thought this place would be more relevant.